# Aptana does not start on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: aptana-studio

Trying to install Aptana 2.0.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 but after install it is not working. I suppose I am missing something. My steps of installation:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk libjpeg62 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 git-core
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 git-core
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Downloading standalone version of Aptana:

```
sudo unzip Aptana_Studio_Setup_Linux_x86_2.0.5.zip -d /opt
Going by Nautilus to the /opt/Aptana Studio/
```

Now, I launched Aptana Studio, and I get this screen.

[image: pic]

for a 2-3 seconds an after that disappear and nothing is happen

I spent a lot of time by trying different tutorials over the web. But nothing can help me.

Comment: I install Ubuntu - 14.04 - same issue

Comment: Edit you question appropriately and explain you problem in much detail as possible.

Comment: hope my editing will help what I am trying. Sorry for my english

Comment: Have you tried starting it from the command line?

Comment: No I am just clicking on the icon from Nautilus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to download the latest Aptana Studio.

Here is how I did it.  I used the same commands as you did, with these exceptions:

1. Didn't install

   sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk libjpeg62 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 git-core
   sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 git-core
2. Installed Chromium Browser
3. Downloaded and Installed Aptana Studio 3.4.2 the same way.
4. Double clicked on AptanaStudio3 under /opt/Aptana_Studio_3, and it works.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but i need exactly 2.0.5 version of Aptana. It is very important for me

Comment: I don't think that 2.0.5 will work with 14.04.  Tried, and it didn't.  Why can't you use version 3?

Comment: It is not working with 13.04 also. Aptana 2.0.5 more suitable for my web development

Comment: I have tried 2.0.5 on 12.04 - 14.04, and it won't work, with any of them with either oracle Java or open jdk.  On the other hand, version 3 works with all, and either Java. Maybe you can upgrade your project to work with version 3.

Comment: Hm. Thats really bad. A thought I miss somenthing. So I have no choise. I will try to work with 3 version. Thanks for helping